# Объединить несколько массивов в один javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть три массива с повторяющимся `_id` ключами, нужно их смержить или объединить в один, при этом что-бы не было дубликатов с ключём `_id`.

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    '_id': '1',
    'man': 20
  },
  {
    '_id': '2',
    'man': 15
  }
]


var arr2 = [
  {
    '_id': '1',
    'woman': 13
  },
  {
    '_id': '2',
    'woman': 18
  }
]

var arr3 = [
  {
    '_id': '1',
    'animal': 2
  },
  {
    '_id': '2',
    'animal': 8
  }
]
```

Нужно что-бы в результате получилось так

```
[
   {
    '_id': '1',
    'woman': 13
    'man': 20
    'animal': 2
  },
  {
    '_id': '2',
    'woman': 18
    'man': 15
    'animal': 8
  }
]
```

Каким образом сделать объединение массивов эффективно в одном цикле? Или может есть специальный метод lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr1 = [{ _id: '1', man: 20 }, { _id: '2', man: 15 }]
  , arr2 = [{ _id: '1', woman: 13 }, { _id: '2', woman: 18 }]
  , arr3 = [{ _id: '1', animal: 2 }, { _id: '2', animal: 8 }];

var id = '_id'
  , data = {};
[].concat(arr1, arr2, arr3).forEach(function(item) {
  if (id in item) {
    var key = item[id];
    data[key] = data[key] || {};
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(property) {
      data[key][property] = item[property];
    });
  }    
});
var result = Object.values(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [{'_id': '1','man': 20}, {'_id': '2','man': 15}];
var arr2 = [{'_id': '1','woman': 13}, {'_id': '2','woman': 18}];
var arr3 = [{'_id': '1','animal': 2}, {'_id': '2','animal': 8}];

var merged = Object.create(null);

arr1.concat(arr2, arr3).forEach(function (obj) {
    merged[obj._id] = Object.assign(merged[obj._id] || {}, obj);
});

console.log(merged);
// Если нужен именно массив
console.log(Object.values(merged));
```